# Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (41.6pt):

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I got this error today in my doc which worked fine for long.
Package `fancyhdr` Warning:

```
\headheight is too small (41.6pt): 
Make it at least 41.61469pt.
We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

I tried to change the `headheight` but doesn't work. The document worked always except now. I think the problem is related to something else? What? I don't know.
It begins at page 47 and stops at 48 or 50 sometimes with warning:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (27.5pt): 
 Make it at least 41.61469pt.
```

As I change the headheight as asked, it gives me an other error:

```
texify.exe: Permission denied: Thesis_corrected-chap-8-114.log
```

When I try to delete the log file, I get a msg that I can not delete it because the file is being used by some other program/app. Close it. Closing miktex editor or explorer doesn't help. I have to log off and log in again to delete the log file. When I rerun the code in editor, it again stops somewhere and has several errors like:

```
Overfull \hbox (11.48994pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 255--255
\T1/cmr/bx/n/24.88 duc-tor Ma-te-ri-al-s/-Trans-par-ent Con-
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
Underfull \hbox (badness 1005) in paragraph at lines 270--270
\T1/cmr/bx/n/17.28 Ma-te-ri-als and Trans-par-ent Con-duc-tor Elec-
Overfull \hbox (13.15569pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 288--288
 [][]
Underfull \hbox (badness 1527) in paragraph at lines 325--325
[]\T1/cmr/bx/n/17.28 Transparent Con-duc-tor Ma-te-ri-al-s/-Elec-trodes
Overfull \hbox (41.95877pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 332--332
 [][]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
Underfull \vbox (badness 2828) has occurred while \output is active
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 365--368
Underfull \vbox (badness 1838) has occurred while \output is active
```

It's like a loop that I don't get out of: The strange thing is that I have been working on my thesis since few months and everyday I change the name of document like thesis-manuscript50 and next day it is -51 for example. If I run the previous versions (previous days' file) it works perfectly. I didn't change anything significant except adding/modifying the text in one section in last two days. When I copy this text to a previous version (day) file, it stops with with headheight msg. I hope I made myself clear. The MWE is given below. I hope it contains min working packages.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{epsfig,amsmath,amssymb,epic,eepic,color,amsthm}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[frenchb,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[labelfont=it, bf]{caption}
\usepackage[font=it]{caption}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{makeidx} 
\usepackage{showidx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}


    \usepackage{wasysym}
    \usepackage{fancybox}

    \usepackage{rotating}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapter}
\@startsection{chapter}{0}{0mm}{3\baselineskip}{1.5\baselineskip}{\Huge\normalfont\bfseries}}
\makeatother

                \setlength{\topmargin}{-5mm} 
                \setlength{\textheight}{240mm}
                \setlength{\textwidth}{15cm}



\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}                   
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.9}      
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.7}             
\tolerance=5000                                                     

\newlength{\mytabwidth}
\newlength{\myxlengthtozero}
\newlength{\myylengthtozero}
\newcommand{\PutBottomLeft}[1]{
  \setlength{\myxlengthtozero}{0pt}
  \addtolength{\myxlengthtozero}{-3.54cm}
  \addtolength{\myxlengthtozero}{-\hoffset}
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}{\addtolength{\myxlengthtozero}{-\oddsidemargin}}{\addtolength{\myxlengthtozero}{-\evensidemargin}}%
  \setlength{\myylengthtozero}{\paperheight}
  \addtolength{\myylengthtozero}{-1in}
  \addtolength{\myylengthtozero}{-\voffset}
  \addtolength{\myylengthtozero}{-\topmargin}
  \addtolength{\myylengthtozero}{-\headheight}
  \addtolength{\myylengthtozero}{-\headsep}
  \addtolength{\myylengthtozero}{-\topskip}
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[-\myxlengthtozero][l]{
  \raisebox{-\myylengthtozero}[0pt][0pt]{#1}}}}


\pagestyle{fancy}

    \setlength{\headheight}{41.6257pt}
    \setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}

        \lhead[\thepage] {\rightmark}
        \rhead[\leftmark] {\thepage}
        \lfoot[]{}
        \cfoot[]{}
        \rfoot[]{}

\linespread{1.5}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}            
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}         


\begin{document}
```

Will appreciate if you guys can help me get out of this. I just took MWE file from my friend who taught me few basic things (before he left for a job) and I moved on learning by doing but still I don't think that I am good at it. This might be apparent from description/code sadly:( Thanks in advance, Azhar

Comment: You have something large in one header. Perhaps the header is too long and got broken over two lines.

Comment: Did it happen on page 10 or page 100?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If you think it is related to something else, how exactly do you think we can know what without the benefit you have of access to the something else?  Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Fischer: I checked for this but this is not the case.

Comment: @John Kormylo: It starts at pg 47 and stops at pg 48 or 50 sometimes.

Comment: @cfr: I have edited the question adding more deatils.

Comment: That is not an MWE. Please read the link I posted. Your MWE should enable us to reproduce the problem you are seeing. If you are posting error messages, your MWE should produce those messages when we try to compile it. Given that the same preamble apparently works in other files, that cannot be where the problem lies in any case.

Comment: Are there any news here?